# Cleverer way to avoid looping over dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr

I am looking for a cleverer and hopefully faster way to loop over the rows of a dataframe:

Given such dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rep(NA,10))
```

I want for the column "y" at the row i, to be the sum of the ith and (i-1)th values of x:

```
y[i] = x[i] + x[i-1]
```

in R:

```
for( i in 1:nrow(d)) d$y[i] <- ifelse( i>1, d$x[i] + d$x[i-1], d$x[i])
```

But looping over dataframe in R is never the best idea, can dply or lapply handle such case?

Comment: Read about [dplyr lead/lag](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) functions.

Comment: Um....`d$x + c(NA,d$x[-10])`?

Comment: `d$x + c(0, d$x[-10])`

Comment: In flexible terms, it can also be conceptualised as a linear filter `stats::filter(c(0,d$x), c(1,1), sides=1)[-1]`

Comment: Just fyi, `lapply` *is* looping over the data frame.

Comment: the dplyr lag is an elegant answer as well zx8754, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using `sapply`

```
sapply(1:nrow(d), function(i) sum(d$x[(i-1):i]))
# [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

And another using `rollsum` of `zoo` package

```
library(zoo)
rollsum(x = d$x, k = 2, align = 'right', fill = d$x[1])
# [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Answer (score 0):

my experience has been that the Ulrich's package TTR is very quick for this task

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10)
d$y <- TTR::runSum(d$x,n=2)
```